# Anyway to enter `debugger` mode upon uncaught exceptions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to be able to pause execution of my script *right at the point of the exception in the source* and then sit at a console with everything frozen at that point in time, typing in variable names and getting back their corresponding values.

Is there any way to do such a thing with Chrome devtools?

Sorry for the n00b Q.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#js_exceptions

Answer (score 3):

yes, look at the image:

[image]

That will stop the execution when an unhandled exception occurs.